# Possible to use the @XmlSeeAlso dyncamiclly?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

Instead of this

```
@XmlSeeAlso({User.class,Role.class,Function.class})
```

I would like something like this:

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Access.getWebServiceClasses())
```

Is it possible?

I want this since my webservice just contains interfaces and if I change the implementation I would just like to change in my factory so it returns the right classes instead of having to change in the webservice itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **isn't** possible, since annotation elements must be simple types (strings, primitives or classes (see [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html)).

It is possible however (in CXF) to override `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.getExtraClass()` method which, by default checks `@XmlSeeAlso` of the interface. My implementation returns additional `ObjectFactory` classes.

Chances are that you're using `<jaxws:endpoint />` in CXF's Spring XML configuration. To be able to override this method, you have create few classes:

1. `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser` must use class derived from `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.EndpointDefinitionParser.SpringEndpointImpl` (when using JAXWS 2.1) or from `org.apache.cxf.jaxws22.spring.JAXWS22SpringEndpointImpl` (JAXWS 2.2)
2. This class must call `super.setServiceFactory()` passing `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServerFactoryBean` with overriden `getExtraClass()`
3. You have to provide your own `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler` (you can create derived class) for your own namespace (e.g. `http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws/dynamic`) which will register your own parser for `jaxws:endpoint` element:

   registerBeanDefinitionParser("endpoint", new EndpointDefinitionParser());

(sorry, I can't provide full example - I'm writing from memory and CXF's source code)